# change current class and load page in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, load

I try to change my current class on my menu and i load the page.

```
<ul class="menu2">
    <li class="current" id="1"><a href="?stat=1"><b>item1</b></a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="?stat=2" ><b>item2</b></a></li>
    <li id="3"><a href="?stat=3" ><b>item3</b></a></li>
    <li id="4"><a href="?stat=4" ><b>item4</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.menu2 li a').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu2 li').removeClass('current');
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!$parent.hasClass('current')) {
        $parent.addClass('current');                
        $('#tableau').load($(this).find(a).attr('href'));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click on `item2`, it's loading the page with the good parameter `?stat=2`. But the current class it's not good, it stays to `active` in `item1`.

But when i comment this line:

```
$('#tableau').load($(this).find(a).attr('href'));
```

the current class change, but the load not work. Please someone can help me?

Comment: You have already removed the `current` class from the `li` elements, so your `if` condition is redundant.

Comment: you don't need to check this `if (!$parent.hasClass('current')) {`  as you have already removed `current` class above .Secondly `$(this).find(a).attr('href')` --this won't work as `this` itself pointing to `a` tag so it will not get any `a` inside `a` .

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little off. Firstly, you have already removed the `current` class from all the `li` elements, so the `if` condition is redundant. Secondly, `$(this)` refers to the `a` element, so `$(this).find('a')` is not going to return anything. Try this:

```
$('.menu2 li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $a = $(this), $parent = $a.parent();
    $parent.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');                
    $('#tableau').load($a.attr('href'));
});
```